# When every closed and connected subset is path connected

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, path-connected

Let $X$ be a compact $T_0$ topological space such that its closed and connected subsets are path connected. Is there any characterization for such a space?

Comment: Any characterization is helpful for me. Is there any (**NICE**)?

Comment: Not an answer. Consider the set $C$ in the plane defined as the union of the vertical segment $S:=\{0\}\times [0,1]$ with the graph of the function $$f:(0,1]\to\mathbb{R},$$ $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$. The set $C$ is closed, connected and I do not believe that it is path connected (*Better check my claim*).  If my claim is correct, then the spaces you are enquiring are pretty weird:  no closed subset of such a space can be homeomorphic to a closed cube of dimension $\geq 2$. With the caveat that my claim could be horribly wrong.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Your space is not path connected.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz Thanks for confirming. Finite CW complexes are excluded. Semi-algebraic or subanalytic sets are excluded.  Discrete spaces have the property in the question.  A nondiscrete space is $\{0\}\cup\{1/n;\;\;n\in \mathbb{Z}_>0\}$. I cannot think of a nontrivial connected space with the property in the question.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Unless I'm mistaken, the interval $[0,1]$ has this property. Of course every compact totally disconnected space is also an example (for trivial reasons).

Comment: Wouldn't 1-dimensional CW complexes work likewise?

Comment: @DenisNardin More generally, every hereditarily locally connected (i.e. every connected subspace is locally connected) Polish space has this property.

Comment: Yes, 1-dimensional CW complexes do work.

Comment: @D.S.Lipham does such space have to be 1-dimensional?

Comment: @erz: Yes, in this case dimension is $\le 1$. Moreover, such a continuum is rational: Every point has a basis consisting of neighborhoods with countable boundary (which implies that the inductive dimension is $\le 1$). It appears that among continua, this property is exactly hlc, equivalently, rationality.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Rational is too weak to imply every closed subset is path-connected. Consider the topologists sine curve. But rim-finite implies hlc implies the property.

Comment: @D.S.Lipham: I should have said Peano continuum rather than continuum.